# Google Sign In doesn't work with Trusted Web Activity (TWA) release apk but works in debug apk

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-signin, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

I am using Trusted Web Activities(TWA) for the Android app. My app uses Google Sign In for Authentication (Firebase). In debug mode, it works as it should. But when I install the release apk and try to Sign In, authentication fails and the app restarts.

I do know that you need to add SHA-1 fingerprint in the Firebase Project settings for your app, but my project is a web app and there is no option to add fingerprint for the same.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, If I use it as PWA then it works perfectly fine. But when I  use it in TWA. firebase auth always fails.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference on the browser side between a debug and a release APK. What seems to be happening in this case is that the package signature (and the SHA-256 fingerprint) are different, which cause the Digital Asset Links validation to fail in the release APK and causes the content to be opened in a Custom Tab.

You can use [Peter's Asset Links Tool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.conn.assetlinkstool) to get the SHA-256 fingerprint for the release APK installed on a device, then update `.well-known/assetlinks.json` accordingly.